# Infinispan Server - directory provider

Tags: java, configuration-files, infinispan

I'm going to "upgrade" my standalone cache to a clustered one. Until now I had the possibility to add `Properties` to my ConfigurationBuilder as following.

```java
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put( "default.indexwriter.max_merge_docs", "10000" );
properties.put( "default.indexwriter.ram_buffer_size", "500" );
properties.put( "default.directory_provider", "ram" );
properties.put( "default.indexmanager", "near-real-time" );

Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().withProperties( properties ).connectionPool().addServer().host( "localhost" ).port( 11322 ).addServer().host( "localhost" ).port( 11422 ).build();
```

But when I'm trying to create a configuration for a `RemoteCacheManager`these properties won't apply and all my records are written to disk.

My question is where can I add these properties. I looked through my server-configuration-file but I did not found the right place to put these informations.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RemoteCacheManager properties are just for configuring the client side behaviour. If running the server, these properties need to be added in the `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` file. More precisely, look for the `cache-container` entry which is default, and then take the cache name with which you are interacting, or default, and add the properties within an  element as per the XSD in your server distribution, in `docs/schema/jboss-infinispan-core_X_0.xsd` file. Look at the [Server Guide](http://infinispan.org/docs/7.0.x/infinispan_server_guide/infinispan_server_guide.html) for more information on how to use Infinispan Servers.

Btw, RemoteCacheManager is just for using a cache remotely. If you want to use a clustered cache, you can still use the same embedded DefaultCacheManager you used before. You just need to start multiple JVMs with a clustered configuration and they should find each other.

Comment: I'm trying to connect multiple tomcat instances to infinispan. Will the embedded cache be visible by all instances? As I understood they won't so I tried the remote cache.

Comment: Ok I made a mistake. Thank you for telling me that the usage of the RemoteCacheManager is unnecessary. I've managed to setup my clustered cache in embedded mode.